# Existence of Unique Homomorphism Implies Generating Set

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

The following question is taken from "An Invitation to General Algebra and Universal Constructions", p. 23 Ex. 2.1.2 (available online [here](http://math.berkeley.edu/~gbergman/245/3.2.pdf)).

Let $G$ be a group and let $\{a,b,c\}\subseteq G$ such that for every group $F$ and every $\{x,y,z\}\subseteq F$ there is a unique homomorphism:
\begin{array}{c c c l}
h: & G & \rightarrow & F \\
   & a & \mapsto     & x \\
   & b & \mapsto     & y \\
   & c & \mapsto     & z 
\end{array}

Prove that $G$ is generated by $a,b,c$.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $H$ be the subgroup of $G$ generated by $a,b,c$. Then by assumption, there is a unique homomorphism $\phi\colon G\to H$ sending $a\mapsto a$, $b\mapsto b$, $c\mapsto c$. Together with the inclusion $\iota\colon H\to G$, we get a homomorphism $G\to G$ that sends  $a\mapsto a$, $b\mapsto b$, $c\mapsto c$. Of course $\operatorname{id}_G$ is *also* such a homomorphism. By uniqueness, these are the same, hence have the same image, i.e. $H=G$.

Comment: thank you! I was mind fixed on finding a proof by contradiction; assuming $H\neq G$ and constructing two homomorphisms.

Comment: @sillyme You were on the right track - see my comment - but you needn't have assumed that $H \ne G$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea to get you on the right track. Suppose some $g \in G$ cannot be formed from $a$, $b$, and $c$. Can you think of multiple homomorphisms from $G$ to itself that act as the identity on $a$, $b$, and $c$?

Comment: @sillyme Consider what $g$ could be mapped to. Because $g$ can't be formed by $a$, $b$, or $c$, where a homomorphism maps them does not determine where it maps $g$.